# ModuleNotFoundError even though I already installed it with pip

Tags: python, path, environment-variables, conda, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to import python packages but it won't work. It fails with every package. And when I try pip install or conda install it says that the requirement is already satisfied...

And when in the terminal I use python,

> > > import mysql
> > > won't work either.

This is the content of my terminal :

```
(venv) C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Mes Documents\Code\Fichiers\13_sql_w_python>pip install mysql
Requirement already satisfied: mysql in c:\users\<user>\anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages (0.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in c:\users\<user>\anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages (from mysql) (2.1.1)

(venv) C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Mes Documents\Code\Fichiers\13_sql_w_python>C:/Users/<user>/anaconda3/envs/venv/python.exe "c:/Users/<user>/Documents/Mes Documents/Code/Fichiers/13_sql_w_python/test.py"
Requirement already satisfied: mysql in c:\users\<user>\anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages (0.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in c:\users\<user>\anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages (from mysql) (2.1.1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\<user>\Documents\Mes Documents\Code\Fichiers\13_sql_w_python\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    import mysql
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

(venv) C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Mes Documents\Code\Fichiers\13_sql_w_python>
```

I have tried installing and uninstalling vscode and anaconda, I have tried messing with python path,but nothig seems to work

Comment: It's been a long time since I used anaconda, but you need to check if the venv (virtual environment) you are using in your terminal when installing MySQL using pip, is the same one that's attached to your python when running  python using anaconda3

Answer (score 1):

`mysql` is actually just a meta-package that installs `mysqlclient` (see that in the pip output?). Naturally, you can't just import `mysqlclient` either because that would be too easy.

You need to use `import MySQLdb`

See: https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html